# MiniDumpWriteDump() function's parameters: Why do we need a handle and an ID?

Tags: debugging, dump, minidump, minidumpwritedump

I checked the definition of MiniDumpWriteDump() method on MSDN as below:

```
BOOL WINAPI MiniDumpWriteDump(
  __in  HANDLE hProcess,
  __in  DWORD ProcessId,
  __in  HANDLE hFile,
  __in  MINIDUMP_TYPE DumpType,
  __in  PMINIDUMP_EXCEPTION_INFORMATION ExceptionParam,
  __in  PMINIDUMP_USER_STREAM_INFORMATION UserStreamParam,
  __in  PMINIDUMP_CALLBACK_INFORMATION CallbackParam
);
```

Parameters:

*hProcess [in]*

A handle to the process for which the information is to be generated.

*ProcessId [in]*

The identifier of the process for which the information is to be generated.

Since either a process handle or a process ID can identify a process, why do we need to pass them both? ***Can't we infer one of them from the other***? So there should be some differences between them, what are they?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's probably just for historical reasons. Note that the GetProcessId function, which lets you get a PID from a process handle, didn't exist prior to Windows Server 2003:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683215%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: But this doesn't answer the question at all, or does it? *Which* (historical) reasons would require both?